# Adding column to pivot query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following query:

```
select 
    msisdn, value, date 
from 
    tang
where 
    date > dateadd(mm, -6, getdate())
    and value > 0
```

With some data like:

```
msisdn      value   date
772102730   1.0000  2016-01-07 08:48:30.540
772125566   2.0000  2016-01-07 10:01:50.753
772108924   1.0000  2016-01-07 10:04:27.940
772136349   5.0000  2016-01-07 10:08:07.183
772127823   1.0000  2016-01-07 10:08:19.773
774521923   1.0000  2016-01-07 10:10:13.927
```

and the following pivot query:

```
select msisdn,r1,r2,r3
from 
(
    select *
    from 
    (
        select msisdn, value, 'r'+convert(varchar(4),rank() over (partition by msisdn order by date asc)) as r
        from tang
        where date > dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())
        and value > 0 
    ) a
    where r < 'r4' 
 ) a
pivot 
(
        min(value)
        for r in (r1,r2,r3)
) p
```

with the following data:

```
msisdn      r1      r2      r3
701048594   1.0000  2.0000  2.0000
720000810   2.0000  NULL    NULL
720030474   2.0000  2.0000  NULL
720049121   4.5000  2.0000  3.0000
720187431   2.0000  2.0000  2.0000
720189845   3.0000  NULL    NULL
720201300   5.0000  NULL    NULL
720229335   2.0000  NULL    NULL
720458626   2.0000  2.0000  2.0000
720512511   2.0000  5.0000  2.5000
```

and I want to add the column of data as following:

```
msisdn  r1  r2  r3 d1  d2  d3
```

where d1 is data of r1, d2 is data of r2 and d3 is data of r3

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean `d1 is the data of r1`, etc? Do you mean it is that value in the date column?

Comment: The mssql implementation of the pivot operator is quite limited. I would suggest you return to using a derived table and case expressions based on the rank and a group by clause. `max (case when r =1 then  column end)`

Comment: sorry for confusion, data it means date of r1 etc. see first table.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the following query:
 `select a.msisdn, r1, r2, r3, r1_date, r2_date, r3_date
        from (
            select msisdn,r1,r2,r3
            from (
                select *
                from (
                    select msisdn, value, ''r''+convert(varchar(4),rank() over (partition by msisdn order by date asc)) as r
                    from tang
                    where date > dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())
                    and value > 0 ) a
                where r < ''r4'' ) a
            pivot (
                min(value)
                for r in (r1,r2,r3)
            ) p ) a
        join (
            select msisdn,r1_date,r2_date,r3_date
            from (
                select *
                from (
                    select msisdn, date, ''r''+convert(varchar(4),rank() over (partition by msisdn order by date asc))+''_date'' as r
                    from tang
                    where date > dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())
                    and value > 0 ) a
                where r < ''r4_date'' ) a
            pivot (
                min(date)
                for r in (r1_date,r2_date,r3_date)
            ) p ) b on a.msisdn = b.msisdn`

Answer (score 0):

you might get better performance using this query, rather than combining 2 pivot queries.

```
SELECT  msisdn,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 1 THEN value END) AS r1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 2 THEN value END) AS r2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 3 THEN value END) AS r3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 4 THEN value END) AS r4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 1 THEN date END) AS d1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 2 THEN date END) AS d2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 3 THEN date END) AS d3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN r = 4 THEN date END) AS d4
FROM    (SELECT msisdn,
                value,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY msisdn ORDER BY date ASC) AS r
         FROM   tang
         WHERE  date > DATEADD(mm,-6,GETDATE())
                AND value > 0
        ) a
WHERE r < 4
GROUP BY msisdn
```